# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue Laravel + InertiaJS + Vue3 + vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

When I run `npm run dev` everything works as expected: files are compiled, and any edit makes a quick re-compilation.
But if I run `npm run build`, the build shows no error but any web url (for instance the /profile) returns a 500 with message:

```bash
[2024-01-24 09:31:22] local.ERROR: Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Profile/Edit.vue. {"view":{"view":"/var/www/html/resources/views/app.blade.php","data":[]},"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\LaravelIgnition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Profile/Edit.vue. at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php:761)
```

I use laravel+sail project and a persitent vue layout, not sure it's relevant but it's not mentionned on other similar SO topics.

I have found several questions about this error on SO, but none have an accepted answer, and no answer has worked for me.
After some investigation I have a lead that I've not seen elsewhere, but I cannot fix it properly.
But here's the catch:
case 1: I can make `npm run dev` works but `npm run build` generate pages with the 500 error above
OR
case 2: I can make `npm run build` works as expected, but `npm run dev` does not compile on-the-fly  as it's supposed to

It's one or the other, I did not find a way to have both dev and build work as expected.

Let me show you how, it's all in the app.js file.
Following some tutorials including official docs, my app.js was written like this (case 1):

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: name => {
        // for npm run dev
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', {eager: true});
        let page = pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
        page.default.layout ??= AuthenticatedLayout;
        return page;
    },
// [...] 
}
```

case 2:

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: name => {
        // for npm run build
        const page = resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'));
        page.then((module) => {
            module.default.layout ??= AuthenticatedLayout;
        });
        return page;
    },
// [...]
}
```

And this part is beyond my skills and knowledge, so I don't know how to take the best of both.

Thank you for your time and any help :)

Comment: `npm run build` should work as is without issues. What it does is create `build` folder inside `public` folder. For now, try to delete the `build` folder inside `public` and rerun `npm run build`

Comment: if it gives permission error when deleting, use `sudo` (if in linux )

Comment: I assumed "as is" means as case 1, not after I tweaked the app.js file. I removed completely the `public/build` directory, ran `npm run build`, it compiled without error, but the initial error (in the title) remains.